Return 50% of random result
I want to get 50% randomly form the result set. What I've tried which is close:
SELECT * FROM Customers
WHERE RAND() < 0.5;

But this gives me less or more than 50% of the result set. In other words, this is not stable.
The second try is as below:
SELECT * FROM Customers
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT (SELECT COUNT(*) / 2 FROM Customers);

But I have an error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT COUNT(*) / 2 FROM Customers)' at line 3.
As you can test here: https://www.w3schools.com/MySQL/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all
The expected result should be making the order to be random, and then select 50% of the result set.

'LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ? placeholder markers.
Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html

@P.Salmon Thanks for the reference, but I still don't understand how to achive the expected result with the link I have provided.

put the query in a stored procedure then LIMIT parameters can be specified using integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.' ?

On MySQL 8+, we can use ROW_NUMBER() here:
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RAND()) rn,
              COUNT(*) OVER () cnt
    FROM Customers
)

SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= cnt / 2;


Hi, I need it to works in this link: https://www.w3schools.com/MySQL/trymysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

@user23296141 If your demo tool is using MySQL 5.7, then my answer won't work.  But...in reality you would likely not be using 5.7 in real life.  My answer is still a good one for anyone else having your requirement.

@user23296141 Why not user better tools, like https://www.db-fiddle.com/ ?

@Justinas I didn't know W3School is using MySQL 5.7......LOL, Thanks for the suggestion!

@user23296141 Just do SELECT VERSION() and you will know, too :D
